# Remainder when dividing $3^{10}+3^{10^2}+3^{10^3}+...+3^{10^{100}}$ by $7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

> Determine the remainder of dividing $10^{10}+10^{10^2}+10^{10^3}+...+10^{10^{100}}$ by $7$

We have $10\equiv3\pmod7$ then $$10^{10}+10^{10^2}+10^{10^3}+...+10^{10^{100}}\equiv3^{10}+3^{10^2}+3^{10^3}+...+3^{10^{100}}$$ $$3^{10}+3^{10^2}+3^{10^3}+...+3^{10^{100}}=3^{10}+(3^{10})^{10}+((3^{10})^{10})^{10}+...+((((3^{10})^{10})^{...})^{10})$$Keeping this information, we now have $$3^2\equiv2\pmod7$$ $$3^{10}=(3^2)^5\equiv2^5\equiv32\equiv4\pmod7$$ Soon we have $3^{10}\equiv4\pmod7$, substituting we have $$3^{10}+(3^{10})^{10}+((3^{10})^{10})^{10}+...+((((3^{10})^{10})^{...})^{10})\equiv\\4+(4)^{10}+(4)^{10})^{10}+...+((((4)^{10})^{...})^{10})$$
Soon we have $$4+(4)^{10}+(4)^{10})^{10}+...+((((4)^{10})^{...})^{10})\equiv 100\cdot4\equiv400\equiv1\pmod7$$Therefore, we have that the rest is $1$, Correct?

Comment: It seems correct to me, although I suspect you're _supposed_ to use Fermat's little theorem to show that $10^6 \equiv 1$ mod $7$, and then the chinese remainder theorem to reduce all the exponents mod $6$. At least that's what textbooks always do.

Answer (score 2):

This requires to apply the little Fermat iterated. Let's denote the remainder of a modular division, say "$ 10 \equiv r \pmod 7$"  as "$ 10 : 7 = r $" then we can derive:

$\displaystyle \qquad  \begin{array}{lll} 10^k : 7 &=& 10^{ k : 6} :7  &\text{because } 6=\varphi(7)\\ 
 10^j:6 &\underset{\text{ for }  j \gt 0}{=} &4 &  \\
 10^{10^j} : 7 &=& 10^{ 10^j : 6} :7 \underset{\text{ for } j \gt 0}{=} 10^{ 4 } :7 \end{array}$

Then:
$ \displaystyle \qquad \begin{array}{lll}
 10^{10^1}+10^{10^2} + ... 10^{10^{100}}: 7 
  &= 100 \cdot 10^4 :7 \\ &= 10^{ 6 :6 } :7 \\ &= 10^0 : 7 \\&= 1  \end{array}
 $

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

As $\phi(7)=6$ and $(10,7)=1$ using Fermat's Little theorem, $10^6\equiv1\pmod7$

Observe that $10^{m+1}-10=10(10^m-1)\equiv0\pmod6$ as $10^m-1$ is divisible by $10-1=9$ for integer $m\ge0$

$\displaystyle\implies 10^{m+1}\equiv10\pmod6\equiv4$ for integer  $m\ge0$

So, we can set $10^{m+1}=6a+4$ where $a$ is an integer

$\displaystyle\implies 10^{(10^n)}=10^{6a+4}=(10^6)^a\cdot10^4\equiv1^a\cdot3^4\pmod7\equiv81\equiv4$

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

As $10\equiv3\pmod 7,10^{(10^n)}\equiv3^{(10^n)}\pmod 7$

Now, observe that for $n\ge1,$

$10^n=(10^n-1)+1=1+\underbrace{99\cdot99}_{n \text{ digits }}=1+3\cdot\underbrace{11\cdot11}_{n \text{ digits }}=1+3m$ where $m$ is odd

$\displaystyle 3^{10^n}=3^{(1+3m)}=3\cdot3^{3m}=3\cdot27^m\equiv3\cdot(-1)^m\pmod7$

$\displaystyle\implies 3^{10^n}\equiv-3\pmod7$ as $m$ is odd